# Different output when using ParallelDo

Tags: parallelization

I think this is a very naive question which emerges from my poor understanding of `ParallelDo` and parallel computation in general.

Suppose, I have this simple code:

```
Do[
  
  tyuk = {{0, 0 , 0},  {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
  SetSharedVariable@tyuk;
  
  Do[
   tyuk[[Sequence @@ j]] = k;
   Print[tyuk];
   , {k, 2, 3, 1}];
  
  , {j, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}}];
```

then I get the desired print output:

```
{{2,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}

{{3,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}

{{0,0,0},{0,2,0},{0,0,0}}

{{0,0,0},{0,3,0},{0,0,0}}
```

However, if I replace the inner `Do` with `ParallelDo` like this

```
Do[
      
      tyuk = {{0, 0 , 0},  {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
      SetSharedVariable@tyuk;
      
      ParallelDo[
       tyuk[[Sequence @@ j]] = k;
       Print[tyuk];
       , {k, 2, 3, 1}];
      
      , {j, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}}];
```

Then the I get an wrong output,

```
{{3,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}

{{3,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}

{{0,0,0},{0,3,0},{0,0,0}}

{{0,0,0},{0,3,0},{0,0,0}}
```

I suspect that this is due to some issue while distributing the value of `tyuk`.

I would be very grateful if someone could show me the correct way to get the right output while using `ParallelDo` and briefly explain to me the reason why I got wrong output before.

Comment: If you want to simply want to give the definition of `tyuk` to the parallel kernels before calling `ParallelDo`, use [`DistributeDefinitions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributeDefinitions.html). The issue is that `SetSharedVariable` makes it so that the value of `tyuk` is synced between kernels, so the modifications from one look iteration can override the modifications from another.

Comment: I believe the problem is that you expect `ParallelDo` to evaluate the expression in order when it doesn't do that. `ParalleDo` will return the first result, regardless of order. If your ultimate goal is to generate lists, maybe `Table` and `ParallelTable` are better suited.

Comment: See `CriticalSection`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're seeing some sort of synchronisation issue here where the timings of the parallel loops make it so that the value of `tyuk` has already changed by the other loop by the time the `Print` is reached. Compare, for example:

```
Do[tyuk = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
  SetSharedVariable@tyuk;
  ParallelDo[
   Pause[k];
   tyuk[[Sequence @@ j]] = k;
   Print[tyuk];,
   {k, 2, 3, 1}];, {j, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}}];
```

That said: I highly encourage you to **NOT** (edit: typo) write code this way. If you want to get any use out of parallel constructs like `ParallelDo` and `ParallelTable` it's honestly best you forget (for the moment at least) that `SetSharedVariable` even exists. I'm serious; only start using that function once you have a very good understanding of how parallelization works in WL and what trade-offs you can make. `SetSharedVariable` is easily one of the most over-abused functions in the language and the overhead it generates almost always destroys any gain you hope to achieve from using more kernels.

Instead, first learn how to use `ParellelTable` and take it from there. Or, if you have extremely simple loops you need to write, look at `Compile` (or `FunctionCompile` if you're feeling adventurous), which will almost certainly give you much better performance improvements.